# Single page HTML report - DOM manipulation by inline javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have to generate every day a few HTML reports, and send them zipped as email attachments. In order to provide some basic content manipulation (show/hide sections, maybe compute a report summary) as fool-proof as possible, I have to use inline javascript in a single html file.

Are there some lightweight javascript libraries that would help me write the required actions, or I have to use jQuery or something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inline as in "in one file", or as in "functions embedded in tags"?

If it's the first case, and there is no file-size limit, then just use the libraries you'd normally use, but put the contents of the .js files inside `<script></script>`. There is also uglifyjs and closure compiler, that can make the scripts smaller.

Comment: I don't think you have any special needs then. Just copy the contents of the scripts to the page before shipping. There is also mhtml/mht format to which you can save from a browser, but the support is not as good as with html